# Problem with Registering Mock objects with Unity

Tags: c#, mocking, unity-container

I have a named registration like this:

```
Unity.Container.RegisterType<IScheduler, DailyScheduler>("Daily");
```

This is how I resolve interfaces at runtime:

```
var Scheduler = Unity.Container.Resolve<IScheduler>("Daily");
```

I override this registration in my Test class like this:

```
  var schedulerMock = new Mock<IScheduler>();
  schedulerMock.SetupSet(s => s.IntervalString = It.IsAny<string>());
  Unity.Container.RegisterInstance("Daily", schedulerMock.Object);
```

The problem is that the code is always resolving IScheduler to a DailyScheduler type not the mock object resulting in the VerifyAll method to fail. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Unity 2.0? It works for me, at least using an instance of the container. I just tried it in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<IScheduler, DailyScheduler>("Daily");

    var schedulerMock = new Mock<IScheduler>();
    schedulerMock.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Mock!");
    container.RegisterInstance("Daily", schedulerMock.Object);

    IScheduler s = container.Resolve<IScheduler>("Daily");

    Console.WriteLine(s.Name);  // Prints "Mock!"
}

public interface IScheduler
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class DailyScheduler: IScheduler
{
    public string Name { get { return "Daily!"; } }
}
```

Assuming Unity.Container is a Singleton, is it possible that code is changing the registration after the test setup calls RegisterInstance?